# flatMap triple nested streams

Tags: java, java-stream, nested-loops, flatmap

I'm trying to flatMap and get a result of list of Strings from three Lists. I somehow was able to do by the following code. The code is working but somehow I feel I have over complicated it. Can someone please give me some advice which can improve it in a better way

```
countries.stream()
    .map(country -> titles.stream()
        .map(title -> games.stream()
            .map(game -> Arrays.asList(game, country + "_" + title + "_" + game))
            .collect(toList()))
        .collect(toList()))
    .collect(toList())
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

For clarification of the logic, a traditional approach would look like:

```
Set<List<String>> results = new HashSet<>();
for (String country : countries) {
    for (String title : titles) {
        for (String game : games) {
            results.add(Arrays.asList(game, country + "_" + title + "_" + game));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, prefer `List.of` instead of `Arrays.asList` (unless you are below Java 9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

first create concatenation of countries and titles list:

```
List<String> countriesTitle = countries.stream()
            .flatMap(country -> titles.stream()
                    .map(title -> country + "_" + title))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then by previous result create list of concatenation `country+"_"+title+"_"+game` string:

```
Stream.concat(games.stream(),
                    games.stream()
                          .flatMap(game -> countriesTitle.stream()
                                .map(countryTitle -> countryTitle + "_" + game)))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Updated answer:

```
games.stream()
      .flatMap(game -> countries.stream()
               .flatMap(country -> titles.stream()
                   .flatMap(title -> Stream.of(game, country + "_" + title + "_" + game))))
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apologies for one mistake I did.....actually the first item in ArrayList is `game` and not `country+"_"+title`

Comment: @Alex Man Updated it.

Comment: I feel something missing

Comment: I didn't get its point? at the end you flatten them. right?